# Improve pandas performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]
I want to calculate the average age of the items in inside the B column. Some items can be found in A column but some are not. The current code I have now is like this

```
from functools import lru_cache as cache

@cache(maxsize=None)

def average(x):
  age = 0
  count = 0
  for i in x.split(','):
     try:
         age += df.loc[df['A'] == int(i), 'age'].iat[0]
         count += 1
     except IndexError:
         pass
     if count > 0: 
         return age/count
     else:
         return np.nan

df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: average(x))
```

It still takes about a month for me to process the whole dataset. It there any way to improve the performance?

Update: A is the id of a individual and B is the list of his friends. I would like to find the average age of his friends

Comment: Hard to given better advice without actual data rather than a screenshot. You should have actual data in column `B`, not a list.  Try first melting your dataframe.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the context and your data? Why are you storing lists in your DataFrame, for example? It also isn’t clear what column `A` has to do with finding the average of the elements in each list in column `B`. Why the use of caching?

Comment: @Alexander Oh geez I have a twin and they’re also into Python.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile A is the id of a individual and B is the list of his friends. I would like to find the average age of his friends

Comment: @Alexander updated the question

Comment: try to avoid using 'apply' which is really inefficient

Comment: You could look into using [Dask Dataframes](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) to parallelise your operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your data structure

Given a df :

```
a   age b
123 25  156,189
156 26  189,147,123
189 28  156,123
147 27  156
```

We need to explode it and duplicate the rows

```
# convvert the string to list
df['b'] = df.b.str.split(',')

     a  age                b
0  123   25       [156, 189]
1  156   26  [189, 147, 123]
2  189   28       [156, 123]
3  147   27            [156]

# duplicate the rows by the desire column
explode_df = df.explode('b')
     a  age    b
0  123   25  156
0  123   25  189
1  156   26  189
1  156   26  147
1  156   26  123
2  189   28  156
2  189   28  123
3  147   27  156

#convert to int
explode_df.b = explode_df.b.astype(int)
#merge the df's 
join_df = df.merge(explode_df,left_on='a',right_on='b',suffixes=('_left', '_right')).reset_index()

# choose the needed columns and rename it
join_df = join_df.loc[:,['a_left','a_right','age_right']].rename(columns={'a_left':'a','a_right':'friend','age_right':'friend_age'})
 # group by column a  and average on b column
grouped = join_df.groupby('a')['friend_age'].mean()
```

Note:
Maybe the conversion from string to list will take some time but the rest is efficient